# select from union result in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to query the following:

```
select currency, sum(volume)
from
    (
        select "baseCurrency" as currency,
               COALESCE("baseVolume", 0) as volume
        from "Pairs"
    )  as a
    union all
    (
        select "quoteCurrency" as currency,
               COALESCE("quoteVolume", 0) as volume
        from "Pairs"
    ) as b
group by currency
```

But keeps getting errors no matter how I changed the query. For example:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "as"
LINE 11:  ) as b
```

What is wrong in this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use aliases for the subqueries in a `union all`:

```
select currency, sum(volume)
from ((select "baseCurrency" as currency, COALESCE("baseVolume", 0) as volume
       from "Pairs"
       ) union all
       (select "quoteCurrency" as currency, COALESCE("quoteVolume", 0) as volume
        from "Pairs"
       ) 
      ) c
group by currency;
```

In more recent versions of Postgres, you can use a lateral `join` instead:

```
select v.currency, sum(v.volume)
from "Pairs" p cross join lateral
     (values ("baseCurrency", "baseVolume"),
             ("quoteCurrency", "quoteVolume")
     ) v(currency, volume)
group by v.currency;
```

The `coalesce()` is probably unnecessary.  If you are getting `NULL` results, you can handle it after the `sum()` . . . `coalesce(sum(volume), 0)`.

Comment: Regarding your last comment, putting coalesce out of the sum will make a problem since 3443+null equals null.

Comment: @Naor . . . No.  Aggregation functions ignore `NULL` values.

Answer (score 0):

It is according to ISO standards. PostgreSQL was designed to have aliases when subqueries are used. [Go here for further information](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/9788.1196662409@sss.pgh.pa.us).

In your case the following change will help:

```
select b.currency, b.sum(volume)
from
  (  (
        select "baseCurrency" as currency, COALESCE("baseVolume", 0) as volume
        from "Pairs"
    )  
    union all
    (
        select "quoteCurrency" as currency, COALESCE("quoteVolume", 0) as volume
        from "Pairs"
    ) )as b
group by currency
```